# Windows cmd . command doens't work

Tags: windows, cmd

I followed this tutorial: http://nithinbekal.com/posts/rails-action-cable/
and I had to use the command `./bin/cable` but this doesn't work for me.
(I'm using windows) It says: "The command "." is either misspelled or was not found."

Any sugestions?

Comment: in Windows, it's `\ `, not `/ `. That changes the errormessage to "The system cannot find the path specified." (of course, because this software is not installed on my Computer). Try `.\bin\cable`

Answer (score 0):

here `.` is not the windows command. it refers to current directory.  when someone says - `./bin/cable` it means the path not command.

> > current directory > Bin > cable.

`.` its not command.

**UPDATE**

may be he wanted to say to run the `cable` which is inside the `bin/cable` directory

Answer (score 0):

That is not a Windows command, which is why it's failing.  Those instructions are for setting up on a *nix box.  You'll want to look up instructions on how to get it working on Windows, if it's even possible.